# The contained_within parameter in the Twitter API geo/search is not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am working on a project which involves scraping twitter for tweets and analyzing the sentiment by US state. In order to accomplish this, I defined a list of the top 100 cities in the US by population and then queried for tweets in each city using the **search** method along with the "contained_within" parameter as described in the Twitter API documentation here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/geo/places-near-location/api-reference/get-geo-search.html

I am using Python 3.6.5 and Tweepy 3.6.0. Here is my code:

```
import tweepy

# creating authentication 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# connecting to the Twitter API using the above authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth)

cities_data = {
'Akron': {'region': 'Midwest', 'state': 'Ohio'},
'Albuquerque': {'region': 'West', 'state': 'New Mexico'},
}

# let's say we want to gauge how Americans feel about the immigration
# policies of the Trump Administration. So the following is our query 
q = '(immigration OR immigrants) AND (families OR family) AND (separate OR separation) AND trump)'

# define a function to convert a list of tweets into a pandas dataframe
def toDataFrame(tweets):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['tweetID'] = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    df['tweetText'] = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
    df['tweetRetweetCt'] = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    df['tweetFavoriteCt'] = [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets]
    df['tweetSource'] = [tweet.source for tweet in tweets]
    df['tweetCreated'] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    df['userID'] = [tweet.user.id for tweet in tweets]
    df['userScreen'] = [tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets]
    df['userName'] = [tweet.user.name for tweet in tweets]
    df['userCreateDt'] = [tweet.user.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    df['userDesc'] = [tweet.user.description for tweet in tweets]
    df['userFollowerCt'] = [tweet.user.followers_count for tweet in tweets]
    df['userFollowingCt'] = [tweet.user.friends_count for tweet in tweets]
    df['userLocation'] = [tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets]
    df['userTimezone'] = [tweet.user.time_zone for tweet in tweets]
    df['coordinates'] = [tweet.coordinates for tweet in tweets]
    df['geolocation'] = [tweet.geo for tweet in tweets]
    df['place'] = [tweet.place for tweet in tweets]
    return df

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame() # initialize an empty global dataframe

# loop through the dictionary of cities_data and retrieve the tweets in 
# each city
for city, city_data in cities_data.iteritems():

    # get the city's place_id
    city_id = api.geo_search(
        query='{}'.format(city), 
        wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
        granularity='city'
    )[0].id
    cities_data[city]['id'] = city_id

    city_tweets = [] # create an empty list to contain all the tweets

    # get the tweets in each city
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=q + '-filter:retweets', contained_within=city_id, granularity='city', wait_on_rate_limit=True, lang="en").items(10):    
        city_tweets.append(tweet)

    # convert list of tweets into a pandas dataframe of tweets
    city_tweets_df = toDataFrame(city_tweets)

    # append each row with city name, state name, and region.
    city_tweets_df['city'] = city
    city_tweets_df['state'] = city_data['state']
    city_tweets_df['region'] = city_data['region']

    # add city dataframe to global dataframe
    tweets_df = tweets_df.append(city_tweets_df, ignore_index=True)
```

As you can see, I am using the **contained_with** parameter in order to retrieve only the tweets specific to the city defined by its **place_id**.

However, if anyone displays the resulting global dataframe (tweets_df), they will find that the same exact tweets are returned for the two cities of Akron and Albuquerque, although one is in the west and the other one is in the midwest.

If someone is able to shed some light on why this is happening or to let me know what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate it. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I contacted the Twitter tech team, and they informed me that I cannot accomplish getting accurate tweets based on geographical location using their free API. Instead, I have to use their premium one for some monthly fee. So I hope this helps anyone out there who is trying to analyze tweets using the free API.